# Assign territories on lead conversion using apex

Tags: apex

We have a lead conversion process in place using apex and on the insert of the account during the conversion, we are setting the shipping state and country that is part of the territory assignment rules. However, the territory does not get assigned. If we manually convert the lead the territory is assigned. Is this currently not available to assign territory using apex on lead conversion for an account? It seems like this should be possible, but we are currently hitting a wall.

code:

```
@future(callout=true)
webService static void executeTerritoryAssignmentRule(string str) 
{ 
List<Account> lstAccountToUpdate = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(str, List<Account>.class);
    partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap obj = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
    partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = obj.login('<username>', 'password');   
    obj.SessionHeader = new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
    obj.endpoint_x =loginResult.ServerUrl;
    obj.Sessionheader.sessionid = loginResult.sessionid;
    List<sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x> lst = new List<sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x>();
    for(Account ac:lstAccountToUpdate)
    {
        sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x tmpObj = new sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x();
        tmpObj.type_x = 'Account';
        tmpObj.Id = ac.Id;
        lst.add(tmpObj);
    }
    partnerSoapSforceCom.AssignmentRuleHeader_element  obj1 = new partnerSoapSforceCom.AssignmentRuleHeader_element();
    obj1.useDefaultRule = true;
    obj.AssignmentRuleHeader = obj1;
    partnerSoapSforceCom.SaveResult[] lst1 =obj.update_x(lst);
}
```

code called from trigger handler:

```
TerritoryAssignmentUtility.executeTerritoryAssignmentRule(JSON.serialize(Trigger.new));
```

Comment: can you post your code here

Comment: @SantanuBoral I have added the code we are running, but territory assignment does not run.

Comment: Do you see the method getting called in your debug logs?